# Error in creating tables using mysql?

Tags: mysql

---

I dont know what mistake i made in creating the following table?

```
create table users(Time int(11) not NULL,
             userid text,group text,
             jobs_running int(11),
             jobs_pending int(11),
             job_limit int(11),
             run_failures int(11),
             queues text,
             ATP int(11),
             pend_reasons int(11));
```

Comment: `group` is a mysql keyword.. Avoid using this as column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is general problem and many time generate when we use some mysql or any database management system related word like e.g. group, by, date etc for table field.
Here problem is you use "group" word for table field. You just need to backtick(`). please note below query:

```
create table users(Time int(11) not NULL,userid text,`group` text,jobs_running int(11),jobs_pending int(11),job_limit int(11),run_failures int(11),queues text,ATP int(11),pend_reasons int(11))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do a simple quotes and this will make your query run , no need to change your column name
Below is running query
Note

```
create table users(Time int(11) not NULL,userid text,`group` text,jobs_running int(11),jobs_pending int(11),job_limit int(11),run_failures int(11),queues text,ATP int(11),pend_reasons int(11));
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the column name group to any other name. It's a keyword hence giving error.

Try this.

```
 create table users(Time int(11) not NULL,
                 userid text,
                 groups text,
                 jobs_running int(11),
                 jobs_pending int(11),
                 job_limit int(11),
                 run_failures int(11),
                 queues text,
                 ATP int(11),
                 pend_reasons int(11));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Mimer SQL-2003 Validator said:

```
create table users(Time int(11) not NULL,userid text,group text,jobs_running
                   ^----                             ^--- 
 int(11),jobs_pending int(11),job_limit int(11),run_failures int(11),queues

 text,ATP int(11),pend_reasons int(11));

syntax error: Time
  correction: <identifier>
syntax error: group
  correction: <identifier>
```